# CSS. prevent line in text to only contain one word

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quick question,

Can't find any good solution for this. On a site i have a lot of paragraphs. Its responsive which sometimes makes the last line in a text to only have one word.

Can you some how force it to have at least 2 words?

Comment: Give it a `min-width`?

Comment: Hm, i don't see how that will help? Its dynamic whidth and the text can change whenever.

Comment: Nope...CSS can affect content...it can't detect it. JS might help but it's a lot of effort for a minor niggle.

Comment: Better word for the purpose. i want to prevent widows.

Comment: Have you tried `text-align-last: justify;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this isn't possible with CSS. However, you could use a much easier solution and just replace the last whitespace between the words with `&nbsp;` (The best approach would be with a serverside language like PHP but you could also use Javascript).

Example:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna&nbsp;aliqua.</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h1bhuexL/

Answer (score -2):

You can't. This does NOT fall under CSS' jurisdiction since it cannot detect substrings. This is either a job for JS or the pre-processor (PHP etc).

If you know the specific width of CSS:

```
element { width: 250px; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; text-overflow: ellipsis }
```

In JS, simply split the line with `' '` (space) and display only the first entry of the array it creates.

```
var str = "How are you doing today?";
var res = str.split(" ");
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res[0];
```

Regards.